# C# Outlook Add-in: How can I delete a User-defined property programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have tried finding an answer to this question practically everywhere I could imagine, including here on StackOverflow. Unfortunately to no avail. So here it is.

I'm working on an Outlook Add-in (with Outlook 2021), and have developed some code that creates some ItemProperties specifically for use with that add-in. Now, when those properties are created, I can see them when I go to View->Settings->Advanced View Settings->Columns, as illustrated in the screenshot.

[Screenshot of User-defined fields in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOv9Z.png)

In some cases, though, I want to completely delete the properties. And as I know how to do that manually, as pointed out in the figure, I can't find out how to do that programmatically via C#. I have gone that far as to remove the properties from each mail containing that kind of property, like this:

```
IEnumerable<MailItem> listOfAssignedEmails = itemsToProcess.Where(
    t => t.ItemProperties[MailExpiration.ExpirationDatePropertyName] != null);
foreach (MailItem email in listOfAssignedEmails)
{
    // Note: The Delete() operation is deprecated. A more up-to-date method must be found.
    email.ItemProperties[MailExpiration.ExpirationDatePropertyName].Delete();
    email.Save();
}
```

... and yes, I know that the Delete() operation is deprecated; however, I couldn't find another method for removing the ItemProperty from the email (any suggestions are welcome).

Basically, the deletion of this Property is only going to be done very rarely (t. ex. if the user chooses to uninstall the Add-in. However, if there's any way to remove that property automatically, I would be happy to know.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really a bad idea to remove a custom property from all emails that already have it: there is really no point since the user will never see them, but you will have to retouch (and thus change the last modified date) of a large number of emails.

Also note that named properties in MAPI are a finite resource - you can have at most 64k of them in a mailbox. Once a particular property mapping is used, you can never unmap it, even if there are no items that use that property.

Thirdly, doing anything Outlook related from an installer (rather than a VSTO addin) is a really bad idea - Windows installer runs in a service.

If you want to make sure the user no longer sees your custom fields as available properties in a view, you need to deal with the folder fields - they ar stored in a blob in a hidden (associated) message in that folder. OOM does not expose folder fields at all (if you don't count the `AddToFolderFields` parameter when calling `UserProperties.Add`). If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposed [RDOFolderFields](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolderFields.htm) object (accessible from [RDOFolder2](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm#rdofolder2).`FolderFields` property) that allows to add or delete folder fields.

Comment: HI! Regarding your point: "Also note that named properties in MAPI are a finite resource - you can have at most 64k of them in a mailbox. Once a particular property mapping is used, you can never unmap it, even if there are no items that use that property."

I think we run into this limit, which makes taht we can no longer add new user properties. What is not the best way to clean the old user properties, so I can add new ones?

Comment: You can't - the mailbox needs to be recreated. Check in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - I am its author). click IMsgStore | GetNamesFromIDs. What is the highest value of PropID?

Comment: Thanks.. ouch... what does recreation mean/entail? It concerns the mailboxes of our customers and the mailbox contains 10.000+ emails.......

Comment: A brand new mailbox. Maybe give it a temporary address. and after you are done with the original mailbox, give the new mailbox the address it had before. You can export messages to a PST file, but after you do, make sure you don't run into the same problem you had before - if all 65k named props are used, the new mailbox will be just as hosed. Check with OutlookSpy how many props are actually used in the PST store.

Comment: Do we need to clean the user properties from the mailtem then before exporting to PST? Because the current mailboxes do indeed excdeed to 32k (is Exchange On Prem). So how to avoid this issue when migrating all old mails to the new mailbox?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to delete the named props first, assuming all 64k props are each set on at least one email.

Answer (score 0):

The list of properties shown on the screenshot belongs to the [Folder.UserDefinedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.userdefinedproperties) property which returns a [UserDefinedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userdefinedproperties) object that represents the user-defined custom properties for the [Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder) object.

---

Use the [ItemProperties.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.itemproperties.remove) method removes an object from the collection (from an item).

Use the [ItemProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.itemproperties) property to return the `ItemProperties` collection. Use `ItemProperties.Item(index)`, where index is the name of the object or the numeric position of the item within the collection, to return a single `ItemProperty` object.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eugene. I studied the documentation on Microsoft for this, but according to that, it can only take an index (int) as parameter - an index I couldn't see how to obtain. There is no Remove method taking any other type of parameter. Besides, I don't see any Item member of ItemProperties.

Comment: The index is the name of the object or the numeric position of the item within the collection.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the Remove method only accepts an index - when I try to pass the name of the object in the Remove call, it won't compile, as the Remove method doesn't take a string as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, I tried looping through all the mails and finding the indices of the ItemProperty I created, and then using Remove with those indices. Much more complicated than just using the "deprecated" Delete method - but the results were the same. The property is removed from the emails, but is still figuring in the dialog box shown in the screenshot in my start question. So the question still remains: How do I remove the User-defined field programmatically so it no longer shows up in the dialog?

Comment: See the [UserDefinedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.userdefinedproperties) property of the `Folder` class.